# How to setup SpEL contextProvider for @Query

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-el, spring-data-r2dbc

How can I setup the context provider to make my SpEL extension available in a `@Query("...")`?

We use r2dbc with postgres.

From what I understand I would need to register my extension with a `ReactiveExtensionAwareQueryMethodEvaluationContextProvider` but I cannot find any documentation on how to do this. Is there a specific bean or `@Configuration` to use for it?

I found [this unit test](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/ad6d2c97b7b03e14fe3233509fd13588fc33db92/spring-data-mongodb/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/repository/query/ReactiveStringBasedMongoQueryUnitTests.java#L235). It is monogo instead of r2dbc, but I think it's the same principle - however because it is a unit test it does not show how to setup the context in my normal code.

Trying to implement it like this does not provide the `my()` method in the SpEL

```
@Configuration
class MySpELExtensionConf {

  @Bean
  fun mySpELExtension() : ReactiveEvaluationContextExtension {
    return ReactiveSpelExtension()
  }

  class ReactiveSpelExtension : ReactiveEvaluationContextExtension {

    override fun getExtension(): Mono<out EvaluationContextExtension> {
      return Mono.just(SpelExtension.INSTANCE)
    }

    override fun getExtensionId(): String {
      ReactiveQueryMethodEvaluationContextProvider.DEFAULT
      return "mySpELExtension"
    }
  }

  enum class SpelExtension : EvaluationContextExtension {
    INSTANCE;

    override fun getRootObject(): Any? {
      return this
    }

    override fun getExtensionId(): String {
      return "mySpELExtension"
    }

    fun my(): String {
      return "x"
    }
  }
}
```

I now see the `mySpELExtension` in the application context, but using the `my()` method in a `@Query` is not possible:

```
interface MyRepository : ReactiveCrudRepository<MyEntity, Long> {
  @Query("""
    ...
    :#{my()}
    ...
  """)
  fun findByMyQuery() : Flux<MyEntity>
}
```

results in

```
EL1004E: Method call: Method my() cannot be found on type java.lang.Object[]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a solution using `PostBeanProcessor`.

```
@Configuration
class MySpELExtensionConf {

  companion object {
    // list of provided extensions
    val contextProviderWithExtensions =
      ReactiveExtensionAwareQueryMethodEvaluationContextProvider(listOf(ReactiveSpelExtension()))
  }

  /**
   * Registers the customizer to the context to make spring aware of the bean post processor.
   */
  @Bean
  fun spELContextInRepositoriesCustomizer(): AddExtensionsToRepositoryBeanPostProcessor {
    return AddExtensionsToRepositoryBeanPostProcessor()
  }

  /**
   * Sets the [contextProviderWithExtensions] for SpEL in the [R2dbcRepositoryFactoryBean]s which makes the extensions
   * usable in `@Query(...)` methods.
   */
  class AddExtensionsToRepositoryBeanPostProcessor : BeanPostProcessor {
    override fun postProcessBeforeInitialization(bean: Any, beanName: String): Any {
      if (bean is R2dbcRepositoryFactoryBean<*, *, *>) {
        bean.addRepositoryFactoryCustomizer { it.setEvaluationContextProvider(contextProviderWithExtensions) }
      }
      return bean
    }
  }

 // ... extension implementation as in question ...
}
```

Note that customizing `R2dbcRepositoryFactoryBean` works for `CoroutineCrudRepository` and you might need to customize a different factory bean depending on the repositories you use.